# Why DevOps release assign write access to App_Data and Logs folders?

Tags: acl, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, iis-10

We're using Azure DevOps release pipeline to publish an IIS website using tasks `IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0` and `IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0`.

The site contains an `App_Data` folder and a `Logs` folder. The app needs to write to the `Logs` folder but does not need to write anything to the `App-Data` folder.

As far as I can tell, the release pipeline actually assigns write permission for both these folders to the app pool identity, but I cannot see anything in the settings that would control this behavior. I can understand why it would be hardcoded into the tasks to assign write access to `App_Data`, and I suppose it makes sense that it would also detect that write access would be suitable for a folder called `Logs`.

But I find it rather weird that this wouldn't be possible to configure - what if I want to call my logging folder `OtherStuff` or whatever?

So, my question here is: Is it correct that these tasks (which one?) does in fact assign write access for `App_Data`, `Logs`, and presumably a number of other folder names, should they be present, e.g. `Log`, `Logging` etc?

And, is it also true that it's not possible to control/configure/change this behavior?